# Customize collection using bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, symfony, twig

I have a collection of an embedded form.

I'd like to customize the embedded form.

I want that each entry of the embedded form to be in 1 line, something like that :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">field1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">field2</div>
    </div>
```

But symfony's [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype) is, in my opinion, poor for this.

I have a form `ApplicationType` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('responsables', 'collection', array(
            'label' => ' ',
            'type' => new ApplicationResponsablesType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' =>false
        ))
        //...
```

And `ApplicationResponsablesType` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', null, array(
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('id')
    ;
```

I really don't understand how to use `{% block ___ %}`.

my Application `new.html.twig` where I have the form :

```
{% block body -%}
<div class="container">
    <br>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
         {# some other fields #}
         {{ form_row(form.responsables) }}
         {# some other fields #}

         <div class="pull-right">
            {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
         </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{# ... closing block and tags... #}
```

I tried some things but since I didn't understand how it works and what I actually tried, I'll not put it...

Can anyone help me or lead me ? Thanks!

Edit :

As you can see on this image :

[image]

On the top there is the first part of Application's form.
And if the user add a lot of Responsable, this is huge. So I'd like to have Type and Uid on the same line.

(Here I'm talking only for responsable, but there is other collection on this form so that's why I'd like to simplify it)

Comment: Did you need your form element should align in inline?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar Yes that's what I want, and I'm using bootstrap. But since this part of the form is in a collection, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Do you ment that collection means dynamic form content!!!

Comment: Like I said : I have a form for an entity Application. Inside this form, I have a "add responsable" button which add a responsable form (it's working).
But now, I'd like to have this form in one line

Comment: Could you share the image of that issue?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar updated

Comment: Your "type" and "UID" element need to be in same line if am not wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157911/discussion-between-satheesh-kumar-and-bastien-nicolau).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Symfony doc is not very clear regarding this point.
To achieve what you want:

- Create a file `prototype_layout.html.twig`:

  ```
  {% block _application_responsables_entry_row %}
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">{{ form_row(form.type) }}</div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">{{ form_row(form.id) }}</div>
      </div>
  {% endblock %}
  ```

**The name of the block is important. The first part is `_application`  because your parent form is called `ApplicationType` and the second part `_responsables` because your form field owning the collection is called so. The third part must always be `_entry_row` in order for this to work.**

To make sure you got the first and second part of the name right, take a look in the DOM at the id of the select html element corresponding to your collection using the inspector tool of your browser.

- Declare this file as a global form theme in the twig section of `config.yml`:

  ```
  twig:
      form_themes:
          - 'AppBundle:Form:prototype_layout.html.twig' #adapt this path if you saved your file elsewhere
  ```
- You can also use the file directly in your form view (in your case new.html.twig):

`{% use "AppBundle:Form:prototype_layout.html.twig" %}`

Comment: Well, nothing is happening... I also tried to add the bundle name before `_application` because the id is `mybundle_application_responsables` and still nothing...

Comment: I noticed in `ApplicationType` you wrote `'type' => new ApplicationResponsablesType(),` I think you should try `'entry_type' =>ApplicationResponsablesType::class,` If it still doesn't work, make sure you got the block name right by inspecting in your browser as I said. Believe me, this is the right way to do it !

Comment: Not in 2.7 I guess because I have `The option "entry_type" does not exist`

Comment: You're right. You must use 'entry' in symfony 2.7. So if it doesn't work it might be because the name of the block is not correct. The method I gave you is the one recommended in the docs [https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_customization.html#form-custom-prototype] Make sure you get the name right and it WILL work.

Comment: Link pointing at the right section of the page: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work at the beginning.. Just to clarify if someone is looking for an answer, the block name is in the form in getName() .. Maybe I was using the wrong name, who knows, now it's working ! Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work !! For Symfony>2.8, `getName()` is deprecated use `getBlockPrefix()` instead and add the name of the collection field + `entry_row`

Answer (score 2):

To bring those content in Inline, and as discussed in chat.

Here is one of the solution by using pure **CSS.**

Image reference for your required output:

[image]

As you have given the code in https://codeshare.io/GbQPkA , we can achieve the output by **CSS**.

Just add the below given **CSS** in your stylesheet, It may works fine.

**CSS**

```
div[id*="mybundle_application_responsables_"]{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div[id*="mybundle_application_responsables_"] > .form-group {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope this may help you.If you prefer I will share the code in snippet with the updated **CSS** for demo.

---

Thanks.

Comment: Y please remove what I removed from all your post, even this commentary thanks

Comment: If you feel . my solution works well, please give credits to my work thanks :)

Comment: I'll wait a bit to give credits, because this will probably work, but it's not the Symfony solution